# Remove Angular Material Theme

Tags: angular, angular-material

I started building the front end of my web application using the angular material "Indigo-Pink" theme. Now I want to switch to a custom theme but am not sure how to do that. In particular I don't know how to remove the old theme. I was able to install the custom theme without removing the other theme, but this does not seem like particularly clean solution and I fear it might lead to problems later on.
How would I remove the old "Indigo Pink" theme the right way?

Thank you very much in advance!
Any help is highly appreciated!

Best regards, 
Sam

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search for "indigo-pink." in any of your project files and follow the official tutorial on customizing themes: https://material.angular.io/guide/theming

Answer (score 4):

1. Search `indigo-pink.css` in `angular.json` file. There should be 2 instances of that name.

```
"styles": ["./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css","src/styles.css"],
```

Remove the theme from here

--OR--

2. You can simply import your custom theme file to style.css, it will override any inbuilt styles

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to style.scss or style.css file There should be some Angular material import section just remove it.
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwXcR.png)